# How to use apache-camel DSL with thread pools?

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I have an Java camel example that defines the following route in the configure method:

```
public final void configure() throws OperationNotSupportedException{
    RouteDefinition route = from("xmpp://localhost:5222/?blablabla...");

    // apply pre-processing filter
    FilterDefinition filterDefinition = route.filter().method(...);

    // apply main processor
    ExpressionNode expressionNode = filterDefinition.process(...);

    //apply post-processing filter
    filterDefinition = expressionNode.filter().method(...);

    // set destination
    expressionNode = filterDefinition.to("esper://session_X");
}
```

However this piece of code is also a bottleneck, and I want to improve its efficiency. To achieve that I tried using thread pools:

```
RouteDefinition route = from("xmpp://localhost:5222/?blablabla...").threads(10);
```

However I always get an error. In this case I get a "Cannot convert from RouteDefinition to ThreadsDefinition" error. How can I have this piece of code work with thread pools in order to increase its efficiency?

Comment: Flame: How did you solve the issue?

Comment: I replaced 'RouteDefinition' with 'ThreadsDefinition' iirc. It has been a while xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change your code with:

```
ThreadsDefinition route = from("...").threads(10);
```

`RouteDefinition` and `ThreadsDefinition` both extends `ProcessorDefinition<Type>`

Comment: But if I do that, my code will blow up later because they are not the same. That is my main problem.

Comment: What do you mean with 'they are not the same'. Could you post your stacktrace